# Design of efficient cheap talk communication

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, mechanism-design, dynamic-games, incentives

Are there any papers about efficient cheap talk communication, where the players achieve the equilibrium payoffs of a correlated strategy as in Aumann's seminal paper? Or in case no such paper exists, could someone combine specific papers to proove the existence of such an efficient cheap talk communication protocol?

Comment: In some cases. Take a look at Section IV of [this survey](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01519895/document) by Forges.

Answer (score 1):

There are some examples of this like:

[Kim, Kyungmin, and Philipp Kircher. "Efficient competition through
cheap talk: the case of competing auctions." Econometrica 83.5 (2015):](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0899825615001347)

[Kim, Kyungmin, and Philipp Kircher. "Efficient competition through cheap talk: the case of competing auctions." Econometrica 83.5 (2015): 1849-1875.
1849-1875.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.3982/ECTA12103)